# Versioning information could not be retrieved from the NuGet package repository

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, nuget

In visual studio code （Mac）, the Nuget Package extension does not work. I want to know if there is a way I can modify the "get package url api".

Mac, vscode

Comment: Visual code or visual studio ?

Comment: visual code on Mac

Answer (score 20):

for windows, the path is something like `C:\Users\[user]\.vscode\extensions\jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager-1.1.6\out\src\actions\add-methods\fetchPackageVersions.js` and the change is on line 15 (version 6.0.10),

original:

```
node_fetch_1.default(`${versionsUrl}${selectedPackageName}/index.json`, utils_1.getFetchOptions(vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('http')))
```

updated:

```
node_fetch_1.default(`${versionsUrl}${selectedPackageName.toLowerCase()}/index.json`, utils_1.getFetchOptions(vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('http')))
```

Answer (score 14):

Go to the following location in your file directory using cd command and modify the js file:

```
cd /Users/UserName/.vscode/extensions/jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager-1.1.6/out/src/actions/add-methods/fetchPackageVersions.js
```

Add the `toLowerCase()` method to the selectedPackageName and then restart the VS Code.

Comment: Ciao, try to format better your answer: put cd command in bracket like `this` to make answer more readble.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. This is my first answer in stackOverflow. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You need to be a lot more concise and clear. I figured this out eventually, but you should have noted it requires more than one edit.

Comment: node_fetch_1.default(`${versionsUrl}${selectedPackageName.toLowerCase()}/index.json`

Comment: This thread helped me https://github.com/jmrog/vscode-nuget-package-manager/issues/48

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the Package with the dotnet add command:

```
dotnet add package System.Text.Json
```

(Obviously I asume you have dotnet working ! [Or download here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet))